# How to assign some points to certain products?

Tags: magento-1.9

A client of mine would like to assign a certain number of points to some products. The purpose is to have a situation linke this:

product A - price 10$ + n points (e.g. 10pt) //
product B - price 4$ + n points (e.g. 4pt) //
product C - price 14$ + n points (e.g. 6pt)

When checking out the customer, in addition to the total price, should also have the total number of points gained buying those 3 products.
E.G. 28$, 20pts.

Is it possible? Is there any way or any extension for this aim?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar to this using [custom attributes](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-attributes-work-in-magento).

You can create a new attribute called "Points" for example and assign it to your products, then on the checkout/cart page you can get the sum of the values using something like this:

```
$pointsCount = 0;

foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item) :
    $_product = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
    $pointsCount += (int) $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('points')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
endforeach

echo $pointsCount;
```

You might need to tweak that depending on your needs but it should point you in the right direction.